# Custom Sort array objects in discord.js embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

**Here's my code**

```js
const Command = require("../../structures/command");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const data = require("../../data/Data.json");

module.exports = class B extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: "b",
      aliases: ["B"],
      category: "",
    });
  }

  async run(message, args, server) {
    const Name = args[0];

    const filtered = data.filter((b) => b.name === Name);

    const [
      { name, region, location, cooldown, reqs, rewards, thirdRewards, teams },
    ] = filtered;

    const Team_1_pokesName = teams[[0]].map((t) => t.name).join("\n");
    const Team_1_pokesMove = teams[[0]].map((t) => t.moves).join("\n");
    const Team_2_pokesName = teams[[1]].map((t) => t.name).join("\n");
    const Team_2_pokesMove = teams[[1]].map((t) => t.moves).join("\n");
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(name)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .addField("Region", `${region}`, true)
      .addField("Location", `${location}`, true)
      .addField("Cooldown", `${cooldown}`)
      .addField(
        "Requirement/s",
        `${JSON.stringify(reqs).replace(/[\[\]"]+/g, "")}`
      )
      .addField("Team #1", `${Team_1_pokesName}\n${Team_1_pokesMove}`, true)
      .addField("Team #2", `${Team_2_pokesName}\n${Team_2_pokesMove}`, true)
      // .addField("Team #3", teams[[3]], true)
      // .addField("Team #4", teams[[4]], true)  // .... and so on
      .addField(
        "Rewards",
        `${JSON.stringify(rewards).replace(/[\[\]"]+/g, "")}`
      )
      .addField(
        "Third Rewards",
        `${JSON.stringify(thirdRewards).replace(/[\[\]"]+/g, "")}`
      );
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
};
```

Currently, it shows something like [this](https://kyoyo.is-ne.at/R97am8.png). So, is it possible to add teams inside the bracket for each of them? Here's an [example.](https://kyoyo.is-ne.at/6SeFOz.png). And I'm getting an error while adding the `arg` in lowercase and `Team_2_pokesMove` or `Team_3_pokesMove` `undefined` for the ones which don't have 2nd or 3rd object.

**Here's an example of the Data.json**
[Click here](https://sourceb.in/t8085kljzH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of `.filter()` you could use the [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method which returns the first found item in an array. So, it either returns the found object, or `undefined`; this way you only need to destructure the object.

If you want to accept case-insensitive args, you can use [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to convert both the user submitted argument and `name` to lowercase and compare them that way.

You could use [`.addFields()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) to add an array of fields to the embed and iterate over the `teams` to create a new field for every single team. By iterating over them, you don't have to create new `Team_1_pokesName`-like variables for every team, it will work with any number of teams received from the JSON file.

For the fields' name you can use the indices (plus one), and for the value you can loop over your data and create a new string using template literals and joining the `moves`.

Also, instead of that ugly regex, you could just use the built-in [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to create a string from the array elements.

Check out the working code below:

```js
module.exports = class B extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'b',
      aliases: ['B'],
      category: '',
    });
  }

  async run(message, args, server) {
    const found = data.find((d) => d.name.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase());

    if (!found)
      return message.channel.send(`Can't find anything with the name of _"${args[0]}"_`);

    const {
      cooldown,
      location,
      name,
      region,
      reqs,
      rewards,
      teams,
      thirdRewards,
    } = found;

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(name)
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .addField('Region', region, true)
      .addField('Location', location, true)
      .addField('Cooldown', cooldown)
      .addField('Requirement/s', reqs.join(', '))
      .addFields(
        teams.map((team, i) => ({
          inline: true,
          name: `Team #${i + 1}`,
          value: team
            .map((e) => `${e.name} (${e.moves.join(', ')})`)
            .join('\n'),
        })),
      )
      .addField('Rewards', rewards.join(', '))
      .addField('Third Rewards', thirdRewards.join(', '));
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
};
```

[image]